# skip tabindex for iframe

Tags: html

I have an iframe inside which I got some input element .When I tab the tab first focuses on the iframe and then only for input element.I don't want the focus on iframe I just want the focus to be displayed only for input element.
   Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to assign tabindex=100 for iframe and tabindex = 1 for input. You might also want to just focus on input after page loads like

```
$('document').ready(function(){ $('#input').focus(); });
```

if you use jquery of course, otherwise you can do it in plain js